# Is it possible to un-nest (or re-nest) a selector block in LESS?

Tags: less

Say I have some LESS styling like:

```
.some-context {
    .some-parent {
        .some-nav {
            a {
                color: blue;
                &.active { color: black; text-decoration: underline; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, we were styling links within one particular deep context in a certain way.

But now we have a *second* context that needs the same link styling.

I know I can use `&` to repeat the parent selector, but is there a way to "unset" the parent selector? Instead of re-using/re-arraging the parent selector, I want to *discard* it.

(I have used `&:extend()` to "steal" styling of other parts of the page from another context, but ends up quite fragile — quietly breaking whenever the other code/nesting ever changes. So I'm looking for alternatives.)

Is there a way to do something like:

```
// (deep within a nested context)
a, ⅋ .other-context a {
 // …
}
```

…where whatever actual syntax "⅋" is standing in for would mean "reset the context and discard all parent selectors"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible (as of December 2018), but there is an open github feature request that can be found [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075). However, if you consider the option of switching to SASS, then you could use its `@at-root` directive.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like some specific syntax was proposed starting at https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075#issuecomment-13011794